# Extracting frames with FFmpeg yields low resolution color

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to extract the frames in a video:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 24000/1001 frame%08d.png`.
This works, however the resulting frames have noticeably lower color resolution, particularly in places where a red meets a different color. Here's an example of what I mean.

This is what the video looks like in MPC-HC:
[image: This is what the video looks like in MPC-HC.]

This is what the same frame looks like, extracted by FFmpeg:
[image: This is what the same frame looks like, extracted by FFmpeg.]

As you can see, besides the red edge lacking resolution, the shade of red is also different. Both images are in the same resolution (1920x1080), and these are PNGs, so it's not a problem of lossy compression. I would guess it's either a problem during decoding, or during colorspace conversion, but I'm not sure how to tell FFmpeg to preserve as much of the original information as possible.

Comment: Can you please share `input.mkv` or a small part of it? (share using Google Drive for example).

Comment: Sure. https://drive.google.com/file/d/10dg9KczNpIJxBbq1ZRmVeurHZIBFikfw/view?usp=sharing
You can see the effect on frame00000050.png.

Comment: I don't know how to fix the edges. We may fix the colors using the following command: `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 24000/1001 -vf "scale=in_color_matrix=bt709" frame%08d.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg method for converting from yuv420p to rgb24 pixel format, uses lower quality interpolation method.

We may improve the quality by converting from yuv420p to yuv444p using [Lanczos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) interpolation method, then converting from yuv444p to rgb24:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -r 24000/1001 -vf "scale=sws_flags=lanczos:in_color_matrix=bt709,format=yuv444p" frame%08d.png`

---

- `scale=sws_flags=lanczos` selects Lanczos interpolation method when upscaling U and V chroma channels (inverting the [Chroma subsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)).
- `format=yuv444p` forces the output format of `scale` filter to be `yuv444p`.
  The conversion to rgb24 format is performed implicitly for PNG output images.
- `in_color_matrix=bt709` is used for fixing the color inaccuracy.

Note that the default conversion resample `sws_flags=neighbor` ("Nearest Neighbor" interpolation) that is faster, but with lower quality.

---

Result:
[image]

---

Note:
I didn't check the exact interpolation method used by MPC-HC.
The used method is higher quality interpolation compared to Nearest Neighbor method.